# rails / writing generators / how to normalize indentations, alignments, line breaks...?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Getting into writing generators, I haven't found yet a way to correctly handle formatting

Unwanted line breaks occurs all around, indentations gets easily broken, etc... The output then looks quite weird

I tried to cleanup the generated files by running some `rubocop -a` on them, that solves almost all but the line breaks. That is, it feels like there might be a better approach. Thx in advance for any experienced advices

Comment: u can add rubocop to precommit

Comment: the generator is aimed to end up in a gem, it will generates files. I'd prefer to be able to correct it before those files are generated - provided to the end user